# Retain emoticons, Java Regex

Tags: java, regex, emoticons

I have a program which filters the string and retains the english characters and the emoticons. I am trying to get a regular expression which keeps the emoticons like :) , :D , :( etc but takes out single ':' or '(' or ')' ... Basically I want ':' and ')' together else I need to filter them....In my program I am able to keep the emoticons but I am also getting : and ) along with it....Can you please help me out?

```
String pattern = "[^\\w^\\s^(:))]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
text = m.replaceAll("");
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Keep in mind, we all hate IM clients and other programs, replacing such things in pieces of code or other uncommon text with their images. The most common is `8)`

Comment: offtopic: @kirilloid _no, the most common are `(e)` and `(n)`_

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use grouping parenthesis inside square brackets. This doesn't work since inside square brackets parenthesis lose their special meaning.

Square brackets define a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which is a single [atom](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html), not a sequence of atoms. Instead, you should simply use a two-branch alternative: one for `:` and one for a parenthesis, `D` etc and use [look-ahead and look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in each branch.

You can find more info about regular expression syntax [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Also, you may give some consideration to more complex emoticons like `:-)`.